# Windows 8 Hyper-v run script on guest

Tags: c#, hyper-v

I am looking to replace a Virtual Box solution with MS Hyper-V since I have had many problems with non-Reproducible issues in my automated test-suite using Virtual Box. I have a Windows 8.1 computer I will be using to run the tests on.

### The current Virtual Box flow:

1. Start a VM
2. Reset snapshot
3. Use C# to transfer files to Guest OS through the network
4. Use Virtual Box to trigger the transferred .exe file to start automated tests.

I see people using Powershell Scripts and WMI to start and stop their Hyper-V VMs, but I don't see any way to trigger the transferred files on the Guest OS.

Am I missing an API that I can use? Otherwise how could I trigger the EXE on the guest OS programmatically?

Comment: You don't necessarily need WMI to work with Hyper-V since Hyper-V provides PowerShell cmdlets which you could use instead. I suggest looking into using those. Regarding starting a process on the remote machine, it could also be done via WMI, but I'd probably look into PowerShell remoting instead. PowerShell remoting is both powerful and generally easy to work with. _Some_ commands related to remoting are `Enable-PSRemoting`, `New-PSSession`, `Enter-PSSession` and `Invoke-Command`. Best of luck to you!

Comment: @robert.westerlund if you make an answer I will set it as the one. You helped me get on the correct path. I ended up using `New-PSSession` and `Invoke-Command`

Comment: If you think you can, just write an answer explaining how you ended up solving it so that someone with the same problem can find your solution and be helped by it. Since you have already solved your problem yourself I believe the next person with the same issue is more helped by you writing the answer than if I would write it (since you know what issues you were having and your train of thought). Glad you were able to solve your problem and glad I could assist along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`. I will share the main code chunk I used to do each step so future users can get help.

### The Main Code Chunk

```
    var ps = PowerShell.Create();
    //Restore Snapshots
    ps.AddCommand("Restore-VMSnapshot");
    ps.AddParameter("Name", snapshot);
    ps.AddParameter("VMName", vmName);
    ps.AddParameter("Confirm", false);
    ps.Invoke();
    ps.Commands.Clear();

    //Start VM
    ps.AddCommand("Start-VM");
    ps.AddParameter("Name", vmName);
    ps.Invoke();
    ps.Commands.Clear();

    //Get IP
    string[] ipValues = null;
    do
    {
        ps.AddCommand("Get-VMNetworkAdapter");
        ps.AddParameter("VMName", vmName);
        var ips = ps.Invoke();
        ps.Commands.Clear();

        if (ips.Count > 0)
        {
            ipValues = (string[])ips[0].Members["IPAddresses"].Value;
        }
    } while (ipValues.Length ==0);
    string ip = ipValues[0];

    //Move Exe to VM
    File.Copy(@"...", "\\\\" + ip + "\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\...", true);

    //Run Program
    ps.AddScript("$Username = '...'; $Password = '...' ;$ComputerName = '"+ip+"' ;"+
    "$Script = {Start-Process C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\....exe} ;$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force ;"+
    "$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $secpasswd) ;"+
    " $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -credential $mycreds ; Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock $Script");
    var passwords = ps.Invoke();
    ps.Commands.Clear();
```

### Notes

The `//GetIP` section is a `do{}while()` cause the IP takes a while to be query-able.

There is alot of pre-work required with the host computer and VMs to make this system function, which I will not get into here as google explains those parts better than me.

The flow is designed to match another system which uses Virtual Box, so it may seems a bit inefficient.
This obviously needs to be modified to fit each situation, but should be a good starting point for Hyper-V Automation.

Comment: Well written! Upvoted your answer. Could you comment on why you are mixing execution between a `ps1` file and creating commands in C# instead of doing everything as one of the two approaches?

Comment: @robert.westerlund I needed to do a lot of it in C# since I had other business logic that was mixed with this code that was C# only. I would have made the the `ps1` file C# as well, but struggled with the conversion, I couldn't find alot of info on `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`. I ended up just using the `ps1` script I built to test the idea.

Comment: Updated so remove the need for the ps1 file, so there is now only the one technology.

Answer (score 0):

A very usefull PowerShell CmdLet to transfert files to VM is Copy-VMFile.

Syntax is explained here :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn464282.aspx

Hope this helps !